# Распознать наименования товара по пользовательским данным на Python

Tags: python, синтаксический-анализ, анализ, классификация-текста

Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеки для решения следующей задачи на Python.
Нужно по пользовательской записи/вводу понять какой конкретно товар имеется ввиду.
То есть например пользователь ввел афон11 или айфон-11 или iphone11  и скрипт должен понять что это товар - iPhone 11.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеку для анализа текста, которая поможет в решении этой задачи.

Answer (score 2):

А почему только iphone? А "помидоры", "томаты", помидорчики", "помидорина" и "помид." за одно распознавать как единый объект ваша программа не должна? Нет такой библиотеки. И такие наборы -  нужные именно вам - вы должны набрать самостоятельно. После этого  поиск и замена - дело получаса работы. Что на Python, что на любом другом языке. Без всяких специальных библиотек.